# How to create the flow for a Django App authorization token process

Tags: django, redirect, view, token

I am building a Django app. When people fill out a form and click send, i would like to send an email to them for confirmation. When they receive the email, they should have a link where when they click on it they are sent to their application form.
I want to use an authorization token to handle the authentication when they click on the link; so that if someone else would be to receive the email they would not be able to open to the application form.

I was thinking that when the person fills out the form, when they click send the following happens:

1. the client makes a request for token sending some token_data like name, password, etc..
2. the authorization engine gets the request and send back the token
3. where does the token get stored in the backend? Is it into a view? does it have to be in LocalStorage?
4. The email then gets sent. Where does this email gets generated from ?
5. When the email is received; it leads back to the application form view

I have questions about #3 and #4

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to send email with a verification link token attached to it in the end

```
class Registration(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            user = serializer.save()
            try:
                user.first_name = request.data['first_name']
                user.last_name = request.data['last_name']
                user.save()
            except:
                pass
            profile_dict = {}
            for i in request.data:
                profile_dict[i] = request.data[i]
            profile_dict['user'] = serializer.data['id']
            profile_serializer = UserProfileSerializer(data=profile_dict)
            if profile_serializer.is_valid():
                profile_serializer.save()
                try:
                    user_snippt = User.objects.get(
                        email=request.data['email'])
                    if user_snippt:
                        name = request.data['first_name']
                        token = AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
                        link = 'http://localhost:8000?token=' + token
                        subject = ' registration Link verification.'
                        message = "Email Verification"
                        html_message = render_to_string('email_verify.html',
                                                        {'name': name, 'link': link,
                                                         })
                        from_email = EMAIL_HOST_USER
                        to = user_snippt.email
                        try:
                            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [to], html_message=html_message,
                                      fail_silently=False)

                        except:
                            print({'message': 'Email not Send.'})
                            pass
                        return Response({
                            'message': 'A Link has been sent to user email. Please verify it to complete '
                                       'registration process.'
                        })
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    pass
            return Response({'message': profile_serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return Response({'message': serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Later than you can verify the link token with the registered email id

```
class RegistrationLinkAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            token = request.data['token'][0:8]
            user_id = AuthToken.objects.get(token_key=token).user_id
            user_email = User.objects.get(id=user_id).email
            # digest = AuthToken.objects.get(user_id=user_id).digest
            if user_email:
                response = {
                    "email": user_email
                    # "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]

                }
                return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response({'message': 'Not a valid token'},
                                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return Response({'message': 'Not a valid token'},
                                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: thank you, appreciate it. Do you think you could answer my questions above, I also wondered how does the token gets passed to the view and the redirect gets picked up and launched? - these were more the crux of my post, and if you could answer i would choose yours as the answer - thank you